# How can a variable assume the value of another when inside a specific function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was reading Unity's documentation on `Time.deltaTime` and it says:

> When this is called from inside `MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate`, it returns `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

So I'm wondering how would something like this be implemented in C#?

In other words, how can I return a specific value of a variable depending on the function that it is used? I don't think Unity would use reflection on this since it is a value that, if used, would be called a lot of times per second and reflection would slow things up considerably.

Comment: It probably means "at the point at which the engine calls `MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate`, `Time.deltaTime` is set to return `Time.fixedDeltaTime`". So it's not that `Time` is detecting things about your code, it's that whatever is calling your code is ensuring `Time` is in the documented state beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is **not** `a variable` .. it is a [**property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)!

Most of Unity's `c#` API is just a developer access layer on top of the actual underlying native `c++` engine.

See [`Time` source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Time/Time.bindings.cs) and in particular [`Time.deltaTime`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/51ea2ccbe18ad3c6328f4d43b00dc74eef3be5ff/Runtime/Export/Time/Time.bindings.cs#L35)

```
[NativeHeader("Runtime/Input/TimeManager.h")]
[StaticAccessor("GetTimeManager()", StaticAccessorType.Dot)]
public class Time
{
    ...

    public static extern float deltaTime { get; }

    ...
}
```

=> It is basically just an `extern` property pointing into some native `c++` code implementation which depending on the current state of the underlying native engine - for instance which message loop it currently  executes - might return different values